# Minecraft Building Glitch?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

[image]

I was building a roller coaster on Minecraft, then a hole appeared in the ground. I couldn't build there! I tried refreshing my app several times, but it didn't work. What do I do?

Comment: Based on what I can see, your world seems to either have a) corrupted or b) had a really bad render glitch

Comment: How could i fix that? @RetroCraft

Comment: If it's a render glitch, it should fix by reloading/restarting your Minecraft/device. If it's corrupted, well, there's no good way to fix it without a backup...

Comment: Looks similar to a chunk error to me. Restart your device. If the issue persists, your world is corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

I've had that before. Just restart your MCPE account and go back on that world.